# error: (-215) nimages > 0 in function calibrateCamera using Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I'm trying to calibrate my web-cam based on the example given in the opencv samples but when i run the code provided here:

```
def caliLeftCam():    
    args, img_mask = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', ['save=', 'debug=', 'square_size='])
    args = dict(args)
    try: img_mask = img_mask[0]
    except: img_mask = '../cpp/img*.jpg'
    img_names = glob(img_mask)
    debug_dir = args.get('--debug')
    square_size = float(args.get('--square_size', 1.0))

    pattern_size = (7, 5)
    pattern_points = np.zeros( (np.prod(pattern_size), 3), np.float32 )
    pattern_points[:,:2] = np.indices(pattern_size).T.reshape(-1, 2)
    pattern_points *= square_size

    obj_points = []
    img_pointsL = []
    h, w = 0, 0
    for fn in img_names:
        print "processing %s..." % fn,
        imgL = cv2.imread(fn, 0)
        h, w = imgL.shape[:2]
        found, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(imgL, pattern_size)
        if found:
            term = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 30, 0.1 )
            cv2.cornerSubPix(imgL, corners, (5, 5), (-1, -1), term)
        if debug_dir:
            vis = cv2.cvtColor(imgL, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
            cv2.drawChessboardCorners(vis, pattern_size, corners, found)
            path, name, ext = splitfn(fn)
            cv2.imwrite('%s/%s_chess.bmp' % (debug_dir, name), vis)
        if not found:
            print "chessboard not found"
            continue
        img_pointsL.append(corners.reshape(-1, 2))
        obj_points.append(pattern_points)

        print 'ok'

    rmsL, cameraL_matrix, dist_coefsL, rvecsL, tvecsL = cv2.calibrateCamera(obj_points, img_pointsL, (w, h))
```

i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sabrine/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/samples/python2/Memo.py", line 293, in <module>
Img_pointsL, Cam_MatL, DisL = caliLeftCam()
File "/home/sabrine/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/samples/python2/Memo.py", line 124, in caliLeftCam
rmsL, cameraL_matrix, dist_coefsL, rvecsL, tvecsL = cv2.calibrateCamera(obj_points, img_pointsL, (w, h))
error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:3415: 
error: (-215) nimages > 0 in function calibrateCamera
```

what does this error mean?
and how can i solve it?

Comment: please try to print the lenght of img_pointsL and obj_pointsL. Which version of OpenCV are You using?

Comment: @ morynicz both img_pointsL and obj_points are zeros,I'm using opencv2.4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that one of the vectors provided as arguments is empty.

The function has an assertion that prevents You from using it, if not all conditions are met. This time it checks if there are enough image points (`nimages > 0` must be true).

Answer (score 1):

Recheck the value of nx and ny (pattern_size) for the function "cv2.findChessboardCorners(image, (nx, ny))/ cv2.drawChessboardCorners(image, pattern_size)", this should be number of inner corners row and column in the chessboard. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am too late, but hope it helps other people.  Replace the following line:

```
except: img_mask = '../cpp/img*.jpg'
```

with:

```
except: img_mask = './cpp/img*.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not using a big enough checkerboard in the sample pictures. Printing a 7x10 checkerboard instead than 6x7 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to count the checkerboard's inner corners. In my case, it was 8 by 6. This works perfectly. [stackoverflow.com/questions/27348139](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348139/camera-calibration-with-opencv-findchessboardcorners-returns-false#:%7E:text=Try%20size%20(8%2C6).%20It%20is%20a%20bit%20confusing%20counting%20the%20squares%20correctly%2C%20but%20try%20and%20count%20the%20%27inside%27%20corners.)

Answer (score -2):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.avi')
i=1

while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret, img = cap.read()

    print img

    if img==None:#sale el error por que ya termino los frames del video
        break             #si no hay frames, terminarel programa

    cv2.imshow('img2',img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    elif cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('p'):
        cv2.imwrite('image'+str(i)+'.jpg',img)
        i=i+1

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to the above question?